# Why "fera progresser" and not "progressera"?

Tags: choix-de-mot, constructions, constructions-causatives

I was reading an [article](http://www.lemonde.fr/les-cles-de-demain/article/2017/11/07/l-intelligence-artificielle-est-au-c-ur-d-une-disruption-qui-fera-progresser-l-humanite_5211320_4758288.html) on Le Monde just now, and I came across the phrase "fera progresser".

> « L’intelligence artificielle est au cœur d’une disruption qui fera progresser l’humanité »

Why use two verbs (fera progresser) when the simple progressera would suffice? Is fera progresser a common construction?

Comment: *IA progressera* would mean *IA will get better and better*. *IA fera progresser l'humanité* means *IA will help humanity to get better and better*.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*Progresser* est un verbe intransitif. Il ne prend pas de complément. « … *<s>qui progressera l'humanité</s> » n'est pas du français.

Séparons les propositions pour simplifier l'analyse.

> L’intelligence artificielle est au cœur d’une disruption. Cette disruption fera progresser l’humanité.

L'humanité progressera. Pourquoi ? Grâce à cette disruption. Cette disruption *fera progresser* l'humanité.

Plus généralement, « X fait V Y » où V est un verbe à l'infinitif signifie que X est la cause de « Y V ». C'est une construction très courante.

> Le moteur fait avancer la voiture.   (La voiture avance par l'action du moteur.)
>   Le capitaine fait passer les femmes et les enfants d'abord.   (Les femmes et les enfants passent d'abord par l'action du capitaine.)

On peut même l'utiliser avec des verbes transitifs, dans une construction un peu différente. Dans ce cas le sujet réel du verbe qui suit *faire* doit être une préposition, qui peut être *par* ou *à* suivant les cas (en gros : *par* quand la phrase sert à exprimer qui fait l'action, *à* quand la phrase sert avant tout à exprimer la causalité ou l'ordre). Ce sujet est grammaticalement rattaché au verbe *faire* ; on le voit quand c'est un pronom : le pronom est attaché à *faire* et vient avant le deuxième verbe.

> Elle fait étudier Stendhal à ses élèves.
>   Elle leur fait étudier Stendhal.
>   Fais-moi voir ton cahier.   (Je veux que tu me permettes de voir ton cahier. = Montre-moi ton cahier.)

---

*Progresser* is an intransitive verb, so it can't have a complement. “… *<s>qui progressera l'humanité</s>” is not French.

Let's separate the two clauses to simplify the analysis.

> L’intelligence artificielle est au cœur d’une disruption. Cette disruption fera progresser l’humanité.

Humankind will progress. Why? Thanks to this disruption. This disruption is the cause of “humankind will progress”. Thus this disruption will make humankind progress.

As you can see, there is a similar construction in English. It is a little awkward in English in this particular sentence though, whereas the French sentence is perfectly natural. The French construction is a bit more general.

> Le moteur fait avancer la voiture.   (The engine makes the car go.)
>   Le capitaine fait passer les femmes et les enfants d'abord.   (The captain makes women and children go first.)

The construct can even be used with transitive verbs. In that case, the semantic subject of the verb is an indirect complement of *faire*, instead of being placed immediately after the verb. The semantic subject can be introduced by one of the prepositions *à* or *par*, or it can be a pronoun.

> Elle fait étudier Stendhal à ses élèves.   (She makes her students study Stendhal.)
>   Elle leur fait étudier Stendhal.   (She makes them study Stendhal.)
>   Fais-moi voir ton cahier.   (*lit.* I want that you enable me to see your workbook, i.e. show me your workbook.)